# How do I add a Checkbox inside Select Option?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, dropdown

I want to create a Checkbox inside the Select Option and it only shows the checkbox in `Select All Sites` option. How can I implement it?

I am using `react-select` library for dropdown.

current behaviour:
[image]

My code:

https://codesandbox.io/s/proud-water-cvjhgc?file=/src/index.js

Expected output:

[image]

Can anyone help me. Thanks

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. [Do some research](https://www.google.com/search?q=react-select+checkbox).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: Basicly . You cannot add a clickable element inside another clickable element How would the browser understand which one is supposed too catch the click, a specific one or all of them ? You can use javascript to add select attribute to all options and use the attribute multiple on select to allow this

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/multi-select-checkbox this library instead of react-select, It has more customization

Answer (score 0):

here is an example from my comment

> Basicly . You cannot add a clickable element inside another clickable element How would the browser understand which one is supposed too catch the click, a specific one or all of them ? You can use javascript to add select attribute to all options and use the attribute multiple on select to allow this

And a possible way of doing it

```js
const all = document.querySelectorAll("select option:not(:first-of-type");
let selectAll = document.querySelector("select option:first-of-type");

selectAll.addEventListener("click", function () {
  this.style.color="red";
  this.style.background="yellow";
    for (let i = 0; i < all.length; i++) {
      all[i].setAttribute("selected", "selected");
    }
});
```

```css
select{height:14em}
```

```html
<select multiple name="select">
  <option>Select All</option>
  <option value="a">Value A</option>
  <option value="b">Value B</option>
  <option value="c">Value C</option>
  <option value="d">Value D</option>
  <option value="e">Value E</option>
  <option value="f">Value F</option>
  <option value="g">Value G</option>
  <option value="h">Value H</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I may have a solution for this problem what if you do a

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; max-height: 5em; overflow: auto;">
        <div>
            <input type="checkbox" name="test[]" id="test_1" value="test_1">
            <label for="test_1">Test</label>
        </div>
    </div>
```

```html
<p>Scroll down for more options</p>
    <form action="" method="POST">
        <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; max-height: 5em; overflow: auto; border: 1px solid black">
            <div>
                <input type="checkbox" name="test[]" id="test_1" value="test_1">
                <label for="test_1">Test 1</label>
            </div>
                        <div>
                <input type="checkbox" name="test[]" id="test_2" value="test_1">
                <label for="test_1">Test 2</label>
            </div>
                        <div>
                <input type="checkbox" name="test[]" id="test_3" value="test_1">
                <label for="test_1">Test 3</label>
            </div>
                        <div>
                <input type="checkbox" name="test[]" id="test_4" value="test_1">
                <label for="test_1">Test 4</label>
            </div>
                        <div>
                <input type="checkbox" name="test[]" id="test_5" value="test_1">
                <label for="test_1">Test 5</label>
            </div>
                        <div>
                <input type="checkbox" name="test[]" id="test_6" value="test_1">
                <label for="test_1">Test 6</label>
            </div>
                        <div>
                <input type="checkbox" name="test[]" id="test_7" value="test_1">
                <label for="test_1">Test 7</label>
            </div>
                        <div>
                <input type="checkbox" name="test[]" id="test_8" value="test_1">
                <label for="test_1">Test 8</label>
            </div>
                        <div>
                <input type="checkbox" name="test[]" id="test_9" value="test_1">
                <label for="test_1">Test 9</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

If you want you could put some bootstrap select styling on the input forms but this one works fine for me